# Show negative real in SQLite table

Tags: sqlite

I have a column C of type REAL in table F in SQLite. I want to join this everywhere where in another table the negative value of F exists (along with some other fields).

However -C or 0-C etc.. all return the rounded value of C e.g. when C contains "123,456"  then -C returns "-123".

Should I cast this via a string first or is the syntax differently?

Comment: Is that comma a decimal separator? Looks to me like `123,456` is being interpreted as a string and the implicit type conversion in `-C` doesn't know that.

Comment: hmm... good one, all entries have X,NN in the db, so that makes it a bigger problem, since the import of the 3rd party is probably wrong... thanks thats probably it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `,` in `123,456` is meant to be a decimal separator but SQLite treats the whole thing as a string (i.e. `'123,456'` rather than `123.456`). Keep in mind that SQLite's type system is a little different than SQL's as [values have types but columns don't](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datatypes_in_sqlite):

> [...] In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container. [...]

So you can quietly put a string (that looks like a real number in some locales) into a real column and nothing bad happens until later.

You could fix the import process to interpret the decimal separator as desired before the data gets into SQLite or you could use [`replace`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) to fix them up as needed:

```
sqlite> select -'123,45';
-123
sqlite> select -replace('123,45', ',', '.');
-123.45
```